# Error in Tableau :Already an aggregation cannot be further aggregated , for an average

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

```
{FIXED [region_name]: WINDOW AVG([Average Calc])}
```

For for region_ name I am trying to find the average of it but keep on getting an error.

Comment: Can you please give a little more details like your data structure, column names, a few rows of data. The calculated field can be proposed after seeing these details.

Comment: First Column is region_name ( Eastern, Western, Central). Second column has the average of data from 3 columns. Now I want the average of those rows for the region. Example) In this case for Western the average would be 1.84.

Comment: Is average_calc column a calculated field or present in data itself?

Comment: Its a calculated field

Comment: Danish, without knowing the actual fields and calculations used, how can your problem be solved?  I again request you to please share your basic data structure and a snapshot of a few rows, at least